# SICP Exercise 2.04

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp, cons

Reading SICP I am now at exercise 2.04, which is a procedural representation of `cons`, `car` and `cdr`, given in the book as follows:

```
(define (cons x y)
  (lambda (m)
    (m x y)))

(define (car z)
  (z
    (lambda (p q)
      (p))))
```

Note, that for running the code I use `racket` with the following preamble in my code:

```
#lang racket
(define (Mb-to-B n) (* n 1024 1024))
(define MAX-BYTES (Mb-to-B 64))
(custodian-limit-memory (current-custodian) MAX-BYTES)
```

I also tried `#lang scheme` to no avail.

Here is what I understand:

### About `cons`

- `cons` returns a function.
- This function which will apply another function given as parameter to the two parameters `x` and `y` of `cons`.
- This means by calling `cons` we retain the possibility to apply a function to the two parameters and are able to treat them as some unit.

### About `car`

- `car` now uses the fact, that we can apply a function to the unit of 2 values given to `cons`, by giving a function as a parameter to the function, which we get returned from `cons`.
- It supplies that function with a lambda expression, which always returns the first of two given values.

### Usage

At first I tried the following:

```
(car (cons 1 2))
(car (cons 2 3))
(car (cons (cons 1 1) (cons 2 2)))
(car (car (cons (cons 1 1) (cons 2 2))))
```

However, that leads to errors:

```
:racket -l errortrace -t exercise-2.04-procedural-representation-of-pairs.rkt 
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 1
  arguments...: [none]
  errortrace...:
   /home/xiaolong/development/LISP/Racket/SICP/exercise-2.04-procedural-representation-of-pairs.rkt:24:6: (p)
   /home/xiaolong/development/LISP/Racket/SICP/exercise-2.04-procedural-representation-of-pairs.rkt:33:0: (car (cons 1 2))
  context...:
   /home/xiaolong/development/LISP/Racket/SICP/exercise-2.04-procedural-representation-of-pairs.rkt: [running body]
```

I could not understand what was wrong with my code, so I looked up some usage examples in other people's solutions. One is on http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-2.4:

```
(define x (cons 3 4))
(car x)
```

But to my surprise, it doesn't work! The solution in the wiki seems to be wrong. I get the following error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 3
  arguments...: [none]
  errortrace...:
   /home/xiaolong/development/LISP/Racket/SICP/exercise-2.04-procedural-representation-of-pairs.rkt:24:6: (p)
   /home/xiaolong/development/LISP/Racket/SICP/exercise-2.04-procedural-representation-of-pairs.rkt:42:0: (car x)
  context...:
   /home/xiaolong/development/LISP/Racket/SICP/exercise-2.04-procedural-representation-of-pairs.rkt: [running body]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in your code. Instead of:

```
(define (car z)
  (z
    (lambda (p q)
      (p))))
```

you should have written (see the [book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%_sec_2.1.3)):

```
(define (car z)
  (z
    (lambda (p q)
      p)))
```

Note that in the last row `p` is written without parentheses.

The message: `application: not a procedure` means that `p` is not a procedure (it is actually a number), while with the notation `(p)` you are calling it as a parameterless procedure.

Comment: oh my ... how did that pair of parentheses even get there -.-' Thanks!